# easyphp apache error 87

Tags: apache, easyphp

I recently installed EasyPHP 13.1. Configured it to start with the computer but Apache refuses to do it. Looking into the log file the last 3 lines are:

```
29/09 12:24:21 EasyPHP EasyPHP Check version

29/09 12:24:25 EasyPHP ServerBase::TimerProc : GetProcessVersion Apache (pid: 6132) error 87

29/09 12:24:25 EasyPHP Apache  Unexpected end of Apache !
```

Manually starting Apache after this will always work. Searched for the error online but found nothing useful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while in a windows environment. To avoid it I would right click EasyPHP and run as administrator.

Comment: Why does it only work while having admin privileges, and not normal user privileges?